# pointing different nuxt apps to subdomains

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, nuxt.js

I have 3 different nuxt applications for different types of users like amazon.com(for users), seller.amazon.com(for sellers), admin.amazon.com(for admins). Here users,sellers and admin have different fields and auth tokens and won't share anything except the fact that they are subdomains of amazon.com.

Similarly in my case its like this(3 different `nuxt` projects)

> localhost:3000 - for customers nuxt app
>
> localhost:3001 - for sellers nuxt app
>
> localhost:3002 - for admin nuxt app

what I am doing is set port of individual app in its `nuxt.config.js`

```
  server: {
    port:3001
  }
```

But how can I change these to proper subdomains in development while still using these 3 different nuxt apps?

```
(like example.com, sellers.example.com, admin.example.com)
```

Comment: It's not a nuxt problem, this is server configuration. Take a look on nginx or caddy server... Another tip, you can configure nuxt port like this https://nuxtjs.org/faq/host-port/